# Can't create file to take Picture using Camera in Android

Tags: java, android, camera

i am using following code and i don't want to store images in SDCard. i GET Exception, no file or directory found. Please give me a hint where am i wrong !@!

```
  case 0:
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        try {
           photo = this.createTemporaryFile("Temp", ".jpg");
           intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
        } catch(Exception e) {
           Log.v("Error", "Can't create file to take picture!");
           break;
        }
        startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_CAMERA_SELECT);
        break;
  case 1: 
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult( intent, RESULT_MEMORY_SELECT );
        break;
  default:
        break;
        }
   }


    private File createTemporaryFile(String part, String ext) throws Exception
    {
        File tempDir= Environment.getRootDirectory();
        tempDir=new File(tempDir.getAbsolutePath()+"/.temp/");
        if(!tempDir.exists())
        {
            tempDir.mkdir();
        }
        return File.createTempFile(part, ext, tempDir);
    }
```

Best Regards

Comment: okay, i have changed File tempDir= getFilesDir(); but Now the problem is, Camera takes pic but don't go back even i press OK. WTf is happening !!!

Comment: Is your device rooted and have you added the proper permission in manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure, you put permission of writing to external storage.

and What about creating file this way:

```
String filePath= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myPic.jpeg";
File file=new File(filePath);
Uri output=Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, output);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

This code is working for me..